# What happened to Sen?

Tags: plot-explanation, adventures-of-zatoichi

In [*Zatoichi* #9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventures_of_Zatoichi), when Shinsuke is killed, Ichi tells his sister Sen not to go back that night to the inn where she works.  Next day he returns to the place where Shinsuke had been hiding, and finds some rice-balls unwrapped and abandoned, implying that Sen while eating either fled suddenly or was taken from there by force.

As far as I can tell, Ichi does nothing to learn what happened to Sen, and she is never mentioned again (the remainder of the plot is mostly about the *other* woman in danger).  Is that a plot hole, or did I miss something?

Comment: If I could create a new tag it would be "zatoichi" for the series, rather than "adventures-of-zatoichi" for one instalment.